# Mesos-slave not picking up attributes

Tags: docker

I am running a x-mesos-slave container with these attributes:

```
"Cmd": [
    "--attributes=farm:app,region:eu-west-1,zone:eu-west-1b"
],
```

When I run an application in Marathon with farm:UNIQUE, this works fine.

However when I try to use zone:UNIQUE, the application gets stuck in waiting.

This makes it seem there is no region/zone configured.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://mesos.readthedocs.io/en/0.22.2/attributes-resources/ states, attributes are separated by ';' not by ','.